# Setting/getting env in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When setting the env in node.js What's the difference between  the following ones:

`app.set('env', 'production');`
and `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';`

When I use the former the results would be:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
console.log('env1:',app.get('env'));// returns the default env which is development
console.log('env2:',process.env.NODE_ENV); //returns production
```

And when I use the latter the result would be:

```
app.set('env', 'production')
console.log('env1:',app.get('env')); // returns production
console.log('env2:',process.env.NODE_ENV); // returns undefined
```

So why `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';` does not change my `app.get('env')` and why `app.set('env', 'production')` does not change `process.env.NODE_ENV`; in other words they are two separate variables and aren't they linked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

process.env.NODE_ENV would set the node env process,  while in case of app.set you would be setting the environment for the app(just like any other variable). Express is the web app framework build around node, for it to be an enabler. Therefore, these are different variables that we see. However, when you do app.get('env') it would match you to the process.env.NODE_ENV.

Comment: Thanks ```"when you do app.get('env') it would match you to the process.env.NODE_ENV."``` My first example contradicts with what you say here though!

Comment: If you set the process.env.NODE_ENV and then try to use app.get('env') then you retrieve the environment set using the process. While if you set explicitly using app.set() and then get app.get() then it would retrieve the environment from what you had set in app. For more info see here http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html